# getting wrong jsession id

Tags: java, httpclient

public static ApiFactory getInstance(String url, String userName, String password) {

```
            String sessionId = null;
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            ConstantUtil.setHostUrl(url);
            ConstantUtil.setUserName(userName);
            ConstantUtil.setPassword(password);

            try {
                    request = new HttpGet(ConstantUtil.getLoginUrl());
                    response = client.execute(request);
                    final Header[] headers = response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie");
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                            if (headers[i].toString().indexOf("JSESSIONID") > 0) {
                                    int start = headers[i].toString().indexOf("JSESSIONID");
                                    int end = headers[i].toString().indexOf(";");
                                    sessionId = headers[i].toString().substring(start, end);
                            }
                    }

                    ConstantUtil.setLoginJsessionId(sessionId);



            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                    request.abort();
            }
```

not able to get the authentication myloginUrl is...  String loginurl = ConstantUtil.getHostUrl() + "/j_spring_security_check?j_user="+ getUserName() + "&j_passw=" + getPassword();
actually i need jsessionId which i need for the later purpose when i will post the json data.

Comment: Could it be because you're setting it after you're getting it? To an invalid-looking constant that may not even exist?

Comment: And why is it wrong??

Comment: actually this is working code . and it is because i m setting session id manually. but session id i m getting ConstantUtil.setLoginJsessionId(sessionId)  here is wrong and this is because i m doing              ConstantUtil.setLoginJsessionId("JSESSIONID=mzJzfKOYfK1DKZr4Yiua5g**");

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get `JSESSIONID` from cookies, insteed of getting it from headers in "magical" way. To do that `DefaultHttpClient` has something like `getCookieStore()` and the `CookieStore` has `getCookies()` method. Try to use them.

EDIT: Ad comment

You are wrong, and your loging in mechanism is not working properly. If you paste `JSESSIONID` that represents session of already logged user, server probably ignores login request and returns authenticated content. This is called session hijacking. 
So you need to double check login mechanism.

Comment: List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
                        System.out.println(cookies);

Comment: List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
                        System.out.println(cookies);                                                                      i m getting the jsession id but not able to log in.            to get correct jsessionid . first i login my server and then i take the jsessionid from there. second thing is till the time i log in jsession should be same because i am sending this id when i am posting data also. but in this case every time i refresh my java program new jsession id i get... please help

Answer (score 0):

As Antoniossss said, this it would be better to use the standard cookie handling methods. That being said, your way should probably get you the cookies, since after all they are being send in the form of a header.

However, I do see a potential problem with your code. You test if the index of JSESSIONID is greater than 0. But if JSESSIONID is at the very begining of the header string, than it's index would be 0 and you would miss that. You should instead test if the index of JSESSIONID is greater than -1.

Comment: i found out that  i am not able to get the authentication properly .my login url contains String url = ConstantUtil.getHostUrl() + "/j_spring_security_check?j_name="
                                + ConstantUtil.getUserName() + "&j_pass=" + ConstantUtil.getPassword();